# Comparing template type to constant number value

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a better way of doing the following?

I have a vector class, with the following function:

```
template <typename T>
bool Vector3<T>::IsUnitVector() const
{
    return IsAlmostEqual(this->GetLength(), One<T>::Value());
}
```

As T can be float or double (I'm using explicit template instantiation to make sure only these types are supported), I've had to create a helper class, which returns the value of 1, in the correct type:

```
template <typename T>
struct One
{
    static T Value();
};

template <>
struct One<int>
{
    static int Value() { return 1; }
};

template <>
struct One<float>
{
    static float Value() { return 1.0f; }
};

template <>
struct One<double>
{
    static double Value() { return 1.0; }
};
```

This wasn't too bad until I realised I need to create a `Zero` class as well for other comparisons. So my question is, is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: I think this is very common. Did you try to just say `return 1;` in the non-specialized version of `One<T>`? I think this will do it thanks to implicit conversion.

Comment: I did, but because IsAlmostEqual is templated, the compiler doesn't know which type to use (because int can be converted to float, double etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
return IsAlmostEqual(this->GetLength(), static_cast<T>(1));
```

Small, nonnegative integer values should all be exactly representable by each of the numeric types, so simply `static_cast`'ing to the desired type should be sufficient.

Alternatively, assuming `IsAlmostEqual` is a static member function that has two parameters of type `T` (e.g. as `IsAlmostEqual(T lhs, T rhs)`), simply let the compiler perform the conversion automatically in the function call:

```
return IsAlmostEqual(this->GetLength(), 1);
```

Comment: The implicit conversion doesn't work, as I get an ambiguous type T error from the compiler. The static_cast should work though!

Comment: Answer accepted - for the `static_cast<T>` suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let the compiler do the conversion work

```
template<typename T, int val>
bool Vector3<T>::_isConstant()const{
     return IsAlmostEqual(this->GetLength(), val);
}

template <typename T>
bool Vector3<T>::IsUnitVector() const{
   return _isConstant<T,1>();
}
template<typename T>
bool Vector3<T>::IsZeroVector()const{
   return _isConstant<T,0>();
}
```

not sure if syntax is correct, but thats the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
struct Value
{
    static T Zero();
    static T One();
};

template <>
struct Value<int>
{
    static int Zero() { return 0; }
    static int One() { return 1; }
};
// .. and so on
```